# If $M$ is equivalent to zero, must $C$ and $C/M$ be equivalent?

Tags: examples-counterexamples, homological-algebra

Let $C$ be a chain complex over a commutative ring $R$. Let $M$ be a subchain of $C$ such that $M$ is chain equivalent to the zero chain complex. Must $C/M$ and $C$ be chain equivalent ?

Thank you

---

Motivation: I m just comparing the situation  to the category of modules over a ring or the category of groups to the category of chain complexes (with morphisms mod out by chain homotopies). In category of modules over a ring or the category of groups this statement obviously holds.

---

Responding to comments asking for clarification:

Two chain complexes $A$ and $B$ are called chain equivalent iff there exists chain maps $f\colon A\to B$ and $g\colon B\to A$ such that there exists a chain homotopy between $gf$ and $id_A$ and a chain homotopy between $fg$ and $id_B$

As for effort: I tried to prove the statement but couldn't as there seems to be no natural way of having a chain map from $C/M$ to $C$. Since I expected that if there is a counterexample to this "natural" question  it would be pathological counterexample so I came to ask here to get help from people who are more knowledgeable than me about chain complexes.

Comment: I don't know whether this is true or false but a counterexample will not be that trivial because, by the long exact sequence in homology, $C$ and $C/M$ will necessarily have the same homology so to prove that there is no homotopy equivalence one will "need" to really work on the complexes themselves

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take complexes of abelian groups:

$$C:= \dots\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\times2}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\dots,$$

$$M:= \dots\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\times2}{\longrightarrow}2\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\dots,$$

$$C/M:= \dots\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\dots.$$

Then M is isomorphic to the complex
$$\dots\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\mathbb{Z}\stackrel{\text{id}}{\longrightarrow}\mathbb{Z}\longrightarrow0\longrightarrow\dots,$$
which is contractible (homotopy equivalent to the zero complex), but there are no nonzero maps $C/M\to C$, so $C$ and $C/M$ are not homotopy equivalent.

Comment: To be able to conclude, you do need to show that $C$ is not contractible (otherwise the absence of nonzero maps yields nothing). Of course it's not hard, but maybe it needs to be mentioned

Comment: @Max Of course, $C$ is not contractible since it is not acyclic. Even more obviously, $C/M$ is not contractible.

Comment: Is C even a chain complex ?

Comment: @Amr I don't see what the problem is?

Comment: Opps sorry. I confused exact sequences and chain complexes in my head. Sorry